# High CPU Usage in React-Native

Tags: xcode, performance, react-native, cpu-usage

I'm working to reduce the CPU load on an RN app. I've built the app to a device, in release, and trimmed the console logs from the project. Even after doing this, the app is still around 33% CPU usage mostly on a  blank screen.

The interesting part is that occasionally, about after 6 minutes, the CPU frees up and drops to 3-4%. I suspect that a really long loop has been completed but I am unable to find it.

I've run the app in Xcode's Instruments, it's only on iOS atm and found some interesting things. From the looks of it, it's gotten into a long chain of `[CALayer renderInContext]` which is coming from `UVVideoRecorder`. I'm not familiar with `UVVideoRecorder` and would love to hear any thoughts people might have.

[Call Stack + Threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVe4M.png)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Why Did You Render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@welldone-software/why-did-you-render) which will help you track when and why every component re-render ... and hence catch unnecessary re-renders to optimize it....

Answer (score 0):

I think profiling can help you with this. You can get detailed information about work done in the JavaScript thread and main thread side-by-side.

Profiling in React Native - https://reactnative.dev/docs/profiling